# c# multiple tcpclients makes one of the client disconnects for few sec

Tags: c#, wpf, tcp, arduino, ethernet

I am trying to make a robot. for which i need around 6 arduino Ethernet which are connected to a Cisco hub which is connected to computer. my c# code is thread based so it can handle multiple clients. after the work is done the server disconnects and then the client reconnects. the clients connects -disconnect-reconnect at 100ms. in this the arduino Ethernet continuously send and receive data. all of the connection are made on port 23. every client is having different ipaddress.

Problem:

Initially when i start the server all of them gets connects but after few sec one of them gets freeze for 3-4 sec and after that it gets connect but when it reconnects some other will be in freeze state.

If i increase the delay in arduino code from 100ms to 400ms all of them gets connect n works fine. but for my robot process i need it to work at 100ms.

I am not able to figure it out the reason for this weird behavior of aduino ethernet. have done all the basic testing and somewhere feel its the arduino issue.

Following is my c# and my arduino code(all the 6 has same code just data send is and received is different)

C# code:

```
        using System.Threading;
        using System.IO;
        using System.Net;
        using System.Net.Sockets;

        namespace client_server_demo
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
            /// </summary>
            public partial class MainWindow : Window
            {
                // input data is stored into s
                string receiving_data = "";
                int port_no = 23;

                // the index of %
                int receiving_data_length;

                // sonar sensors data
                int[] sonar_sensor_data = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
                bool[] limit_switch = { false, false, false, false };

                // data to arduinos
                string sending_data = "";
                byte[] c1;


                //store ipaddress of connected client
                string ipaddress_client = "";

                //error msg of disconnection
                string disconnect_error = "";

                /// <summary>
                /// start of the form
                /// </summary>
                public MainWindow()
                {
                    InitializeComponent();

                    Thread tcpthread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(tcpserverRun));
                    tcpthread.Start();
                }

                /// <summary>
                /// connects to the clients on port 23 
                /// </summary>
                private void tcpserverRun()
                {
                    TcpListener tcplistener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port_no);
                    updateUi("listening");
                    tcplistener.Start();

                    while (true)
                    {
                        TcpClient client = tcplistener.AcceptTcpClient();
                        updateUi("connected");

                        //for multiple clients use thread
                        Thread tcpHandlerThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(tcphandler));
                        tcpHandlerThread.Start(client);
                    }
                }


                private void tcphandler(object client)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        TcpClient mclient = (TcpClient)client;          // create client
                        Socket so = mclient.Client;                        // create a socket so as to get the ipaddress of the client

                        NetworkStream stream = mclient.GetStream();

                        //read data from the port
                        byte[] message = new byte[100];
                        stream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
                        receiving_data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message);
                        receiving_data_length = receiving_data.IndexOf('%');

                        //remove garbage ahead of %
                        receiving_data = receiving_data.Substring(0, receiving_data_length + 1);

                        //get ipaddress of the client connected
                        ipaddress_client = (IPAddress.Parse(((IPEndPoint)so.RemoteEndPoint).Address.ToString())).ToString();

                        // show the string on ui -> ip addres+ data
                        updateUi(ipaddress_client + " : " + receiving_data);


                       //send data
                        if (receiving_data == "R%")
                        {
                            //send to the arduino
                            sending_data = "Welcome client 1 %";
                            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                            c1 = asen.GetBytes(sending_data);
                            stream.Write(c1, 0, c1.Length);
                      }


                        if (receiving_data == "S%")
                        {
                            sending_data = "Welcome client 2 %";
                            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                            c1 = asen.GetBytes(sending_data);
                            stream.Write(c1, 0, c1.Length);

                        }

                        if (receiving_data == "L%")
                        {
                            sending_data = "Welcome client 3 %";
                            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                            c1 = asen.GetBytes(sending_data);
                            stream.Write(c1, 0, c1.Length);
                        }
         if (receiving_data == "T%")
                        {
                            sending_data = "Welcome client 4 %";
                            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                            c1 = asen.GetBytes(sending_data);
                            stream.Write(c1, 0, c1.Length);
                        }

         if (receiving_data == "J%")
                        {
                            sending_data = "Welcome client 5 %";
                            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                            c1 = asen.GetBytes(sending_data);
                            stream.Write(c1, 0, c1.Length);
                        }
         if (receiving_data == "A%")
                        {
                            sending_data = "Welcome client 6 %";
                            ASCIIEncoding asen = new ASCIIEncoding();
                            c1 = asen.GetBytes(sending_data);
                            stream.Write(c1, 0, c1.Length);
                        }
                        //clos al the streams and client so as to avaoid memory leakage
                        stream.Flush();
                        stream.Close();
                        mclient.Close();


                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        updateException(e.StackTrace);
                    }

                }

                /// <summary>
                /// for updating the form as per data received from the clients 
                /// </summary>
                /// <param name="s"></param>
                private void updateUi(string s)
                {
                    Func<int> del = delegate()
                    {
                        textBox1.AppendText(s + System.Environment.NewLine);
                        label1.Content = "connected";
                        label2.Content = "";
                        textBox1.ScrollToEnd();
                        return 0;
                    };
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(del);

                }

                /// <summary>
                /// for showing if any error occurred
                /// </summary>
                /// <param name="s"></param>
                private void updateException(string s)
                {
                    Func<int> del = delegate()
                    {
                        label1.Content = "";
                        label2.Content = "Error : " + s;
                        return 0;
                    };
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(del);

                }


        }
```

in the arduino code, with the help of the led i come to know if it receives data or not. the timer keeps a track if it gets no data from the server then it keeps the led on. otherwise it is blinking. it is off if is not connected to the server.

```
    arduino code:

    #include "Wire.h"
    #include "I2Cdev.h" // libraries
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <Ethernet.h>
    #include <SimpleTimer.h>

    byte mac[] = {
      0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED
    }
    ;

    char server[] = "192.168.0.50";    //ipaddress of the joystick ethernet
    IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 53);    //ipaddress of this ethernet
    EthernetClient client;               
    char inChar;                      //for reading bytes received from the server
    String inputString = "";    
    int cleaning_state=0;             //for getting the mode selected

    int firstcomma=0,secondcomma=0;   //for separating data

    SimpleTimer timer;              //for timer
    int received_full_string=0;       //to indicate where full data is recieved or not where 0= partial data 1= full data

    void setup() {
      // put your setup code here, to run once:
      Serial.begin(9600);

      pinMode(9, OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(9, LOW);

      Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
      delay(1000);
      if (client.connect(server, 23)) // if client is connected on server 24
      {
        Serial.write("como");
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.write("disconn");
      }
     //cal a timer every 1s
      timer.setInterval(1000, RepeatTask);
    }

    void loop() {  
         timer.run(); //start the timer

       //chek if client is connected if not than try to reconnect otherwise read data from it
       if (client.connected())
          {
            client.print("R%");        //for handshaking

            while(client.available()>0) 
            {
              inChar = (char)client.read(); 
               inputString += inChar;           //concat for string
              if(inChar == '%') 
              {
                Serial.println(inputString);  

                received_full_string=1;   //indicating full data is recieved
                digitalWrite(9, HIGH); // blink the led if received full data  

               // further processing
              }          
            }

            delay(10);
          }
          else
          {
              client.stop();
  Serial.write("disconnected");
              delay(10);
              if (client.connect(server, 23))
              {
                Serial.write("re-connected");
              }
         }
            delay(100);
            //if full data is received than while exiting the loop make led turn off 
            if(received_full_string == 1)
            {
               digitalWrite(9, LOW);
            }
            inputString="";
    }
    //when timer is called check if the full data is received if yes than make the received_full_string=0 if no than stop the process
    void RepeatTask()
    {
      if(received_full_string == 1)
      {
        received_full_string=0;   
      }
      else
      {
        Serial.println("stop");
        digitalWrite(9, HIGH);
      }
    }
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated . 
Thanks

Comment: There's not enough context here to reproduce the problem (never mind that none of us have your robot). It does sound like you have filled the network stack with ports in the `CLOSE_WAIT` state; this may happen if you fail to close the connection gracefully (i.e. using `Socket.Shutdown()`). You may be able to fix the problem by doing a graceful shutdown on the connections, but the better solution is to not cycle the connections like that. Just have the clients each connect _once_; keep the connection open and use it as needed for the client and server to interact.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the 100 ms interval is required for, but you might want to enable `NoDelay` on the `Socket`. I would almost always recommend _against_ doing that, but in this case with your server dealing with a mechanical device with real-time needs, it might be appropriate. You still can't expect real-time response; network hardware as well as Windows itself have any number of sources of latency, and you'll want to make sure that if and when things do get delayed a little bit, your code can handle that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho my main question is the ethernet i.e is the client freezes himself for a few sec and than reconnects. and the delay i of 100 ms is on the arduino side. if this delay is increased to 400 ms and more none of the client gets freezes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved it was not with the c# code nor was the arduino code wrong it was the mac address.
every arduino ethernet need to have unique ip and mac address